# Login in mobile application using fingerprint

Tags: java, android

Hello? I want to make a mobile application for Android in which the user has the possibility to login by using his footprint.  I tried to search some API or libraries but without success. Can someone please tell me which is the best way for implementing it?

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly :) I just edited

Comment: search "android finger print tutorial" in google, first result

Comment: Ok but I'll like to find some recommendations like which is easier to implement? Scalability etc

Comment: It's not difficult to implement. The main problem is related to the Android version because this API is available only from Android MM

Comment: That would not be a problem because the application will not be on market. Will be just for accessing some database from a site. Thanks a lot! I will come back with updates for posting which was my choice :)